# How to Code below Hourglass using recursion in a cleaner way?

Tags: java, recursion

Recently,I have encounter an short quiz on coding a hourglass using recursive in java.I managed to code it as below but would like to accept if any better way of coding this.

Below are the coding portion that i have done.

```
 public class Demo {
        int initialInput = 0;
        int noOfAsteriskForNextLine= 0 ;
        int noOfSpace =1;
        Boolean isReversed = false;`enter code here`
        public static void main (String[] args){
            Demo d = new Demo();
            d.run();
        }
        public void printLineOfAsterisk(int noOfAsterisk){
            if(initialInput== 0){
                initialInput=noOfAsterisk;
            }

            if(noOfAsteriskForNextLine==0){
                noOfAsteriskForNextLine=noOfAsterisk;
            }

                for(int i=0;i<noOfSpace;i++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int i=0;i<noOfAsterisk;i++){
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
                     if(isReversed&&initialInput==noOfAsterisk){
                return;
            }
            if(isReversed||noOfAsteriskForNextLine==1){
                isReversed =true;
                noOfAsteriskForNextLine++;
                noOfSpace--;
             printLineOfAsterisk(noOfAsteriskForNextLine);

            }else{
            noOfSpace++;
            noOfAsteriskForNextLine--;
            printLineOfAsterisk(noOfAsteriskForNextLine);
        }
    }
        public void run(){
            printLineOfAsterisk(4);
        }

    }
```

The output is expected as below depends on arguments being passed in

```
  * * * *
   * * *
    * *
     *
    * *
   * * *
  * * * *
```

Comment: Is this what you mean by hourglass? "*****\n *** \n  *  \n *** \n*****"?

Comment: Our sister site, [codereview.se], might be a better place for this question, as [their scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is specifically improvements to code that already works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.
Here `offset` is just no. of spaces to give before stars. Initially, the function will be called with `offset = 0` which means that in the first line no spaces are to be printed.

`starCount` is the no. of stars to print in the line after printing spaces.

`increment` is just to increase or decrease the no. of spaces & stars which is initially `1` meaning that the no. of spaces in the next iteration will be incremented by `1` and no. of stars will be decremented by `1`.

Refer comments in code for more explanation

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
        public static void hourGlass(int offset, int starCount, int increment) {
              // This is the terminating condition. 
              // If offset is negative and increment is also negative, it means that no. of spaces were positive before this function call.
              // This implies that the lower half of the hourglass is completed,
              // So just return from here without executing anything
              if(offset < 0 && increment < 0)
                     return;

              // Print spaces
              for(int i=0; i<offset; i++) 
                     System.out.print(" ");
              // Print stars with a space 
              for(int i=0; i<starCount; i++) 
                     System.out.print("* ");
              // Print a new line 
              System.out.println();

              // If no. of stars is 1, then it means the upper half is completed.
              // So, here the increment is set to -1 
              // So that from next recursive call onwards stars will increase and spaces will decrease by 1
              if(starCount == 1)
                     increment = -1;

              // Call this function recursively
              hourGlass(offset + increment, starCount - increment, increment);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
               // first argument is no. of spaces which will be zero initially
               // second arguments is number of starts, change it according to your need
               // third argument is just to increment/decrement stars & spaces
               Main.hourGlass(0, 5, 1);
        }
}
```

Output:

```
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution using Java 11's [String.repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)):

```
public void hourglass(int noOfAsterisk)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < noOfAsterisk*2; i++)
    {
        int lineCt = 1+Math.max(i-noOfAsterisk, noOfAsterisk-i);
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(noOfAsterisk-lineCt+noOfSpace)+"* ".repeat(lineCt).trim());
    }
}
```

**Call:**

```
noOfSpace = 3;
hourglass(4);
```

**Output:**

```
   * * * *
    * * *
     * *
      *
     * *
    * * *
   * * * *
```

Essentially, we go through each line, computing the number of asterisks on the line with 
`lineCt`. After computing the number of asterisks on the line, we print out the number of spaces (computed according to how many asterisks we have, and how many the max is) accordingly. Then, we print extra spaces according to the `noOfSpace` that is specified. Finally, we print the `"* "` string and trim it (to get rid of the extra space at the end), and print the newline at the end from `println`.

Alternatively, in older versions of Java, you can do something like this:

```
public String repeat(String str, int times)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        sb.append(str);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and then use it as following in `hourglass`:

```
public void hourglass(int noOfAsterisk)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < noOfAsterisk*2; i++)
    {
        int lineCt = 1+Math.max(i-noOfAsterisk, noOfAsterisk-i);
        System.out.println(repeat(" ",noOfAsterisk-lineCt+noOfSpace)+repeat("* ",lineCt).trim());
    }
}
```

Note that my implementation of `repeat` is just a demonstration and not optimized for performance; using such an implementation for a very high value of `times` could get very slow. Instead, refer [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198296#description-val) in the Solution section, which communicates techniques for repeating Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you might be looking for:

```
public class Hourglass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hourglass(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), 0);
    }

    private static void hourglass(int size, int offset) {
        // print top line
        printHourglassLine(size, offset);
        if (size > 1) {
            // recursive call
            hourglass(size - 1, offset + 1);
            // print bottom line
            printHourglassLine(size, offset);
        }
    }

    private static void printHourglassLine(int size, int offset) {
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(offset) + "* ".repeat(size));
    }
}
```

As you can see the trick is to print a line of the hourglass both before and after calling your recursive function. This way you make it symmetrical, as it should be. It's like printing it from the bottom and from the top at the same time.

If you are not using java 11, you will need a stringbuilder or similar in printHourglassLine(), but the structure of the code will be the same.